# Possibility of making editor templates with conditions

Tags: eclipse

I'm searching for a possibility to make an editor template which generates indexes to ${enclosing_method_arguments} if exists.

My current template for a method body:

```
log.debug("Begin -- ${return_type} ${enclosing_method}(${enclosing_method_arguments}");
```

The result looks like this:

```
public File chooseFile(final String text, final String fileName)
  {
    log.debug("Begin -- File chooseFile(text, fileName");
    return null;
  }
```

But what I like looks like this:

```
  public File chooseFile(final String text, final String fileName)
  {
    log.debug("Begin -- File chooseFile({0},{1})",text, fileName);
    return null;
  }
```